# Why when i run A.exe, which calls B.exe, fail because B.exe try to find his modules into A.exe (caller) folder instead B.exe folder (called)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

When I run B.exe (located in c:/my_software/FOLDER_B/B.exe) from A.exe (located in c:/my_software/FOLDER_A/A.exe), both built with cx_Freeze, B.exe (called) tries to find his modules (like IMAGE_B.png, for example) in the A.exe folder (caller), when it would need to search in the B.exe folder. I think this is happening due to some wrong code in setup.py of cx_Freeze.

I use in my script the function os.getcwd() to get the root path in each .exe

This is my setup.py, which I used to build both .exe (A and B)

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'c:\python\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'c:\python\tcl\tk8.6'

buildOptions = dict(packages = ["tkinter","os"], 
                    excludes = [], 
                    include_files [r'c:\python\DLLs\tcl86t.dll', 
                                   r'c:\python\DLLs\tk86t.dll', 
                                  'A.png','icono.ico'])

executables = [Executable('A.py', 
                          base="Console", 
                          icon = "icono.ico")]

setup(name='A',version = '1',
     description = 'program A', 
     options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions), 
               executables = executables)
```

Answer (score 0):

See in the `cx_Freeze` documentation [how to use data files](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files). It provides the following code example:

```py
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
```

Please also notice that `cx_Freeze` version 5.1.1 (the current version) will freeze packages into a `lib` subdirectory of the build directory, while the main script itself will be frozen in the build directory itself. You might need to modify the above code example accordingly.